# MySql выборка с множественной подгруппой

Tags: php, mysql

На примере конструкции сайта с объявлениями.

1. Дано несколько таблиц со связями которые собираются LEFT JOIN в 1 супермассив, где есть все данные по объявлению: регион, номер, дата и т.д.
2. Одна из таблиц называется photo - фотография товара и содержит такую структуру:
   id (primary), id_asd (к какому объявлению привязка), photolink (ссылка на фото).

Возникла такая проблема.
Собрать один массив не составило труда, а как быть с массивом фотографий, когда есть несколько объектов привязанных к одному id объявлению?

Если у нас одной выборкой получается некий массив:

```
$data = {
        id,
        data,
        user,
        ....
        }
```

То мне нужно получить массив с фотографиями который будет выглядеть так:

```
$data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          data: text1,
          user: user1,
          photo : [ link1, link2, link3 ],
          ....
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          data: text2,
          user: user2,
          photo : [ link1, link2, link3, link4, link5 ],
          ....
        },
```

То есть добавить субмассив в массив данных.

Как сделать это одним запросом вместе с главной сборкой супермассива - я не знаю.

Не правильный вариант (который знаю как сделать):
Перебрать супермассив после выборки и добавить субмассивы фоток каждый раз обращаясь к базе. (звучит жутко).

Помогите направить на путь истины.
Спасибо.

Comment: возможно собрать group_concat() тогда они через запятую в виде одного текстового поля будут. тут больше вопрос "а зачем", сразу все фото по многим объектам обычно не выводят. выводят или список товаров и напротив одно фото (а тогда одно и получать), или выводят подробности по одному товару и тогда запрашивают все фото

Comment: Пробовал group_by по id объявления, но тогда в элементе массива photo - 1 фото вместо массива из нескольких фото.

Comment: На вопрос зачем: там строится слайдер из нескольких фото в 1 объявлении. так что нужны сразу все.

Comment: все верно, group by по id. только выводите не фото, а `group_concat(photo)`

Comment: Попробовал: получилось 1 записись , а в фото через запятую все ссылки на фото. Запрос был построен так: SELECT `ads`.*, `model`.`category_cat`, `model`.`marka_cat`, `model`.`name_model`, `marka`.`name_marka`, GROUP_CONCAT(photo.mainphoto)

Comment: Получилось, добавив group by id ads.

Comment: Вопрос такой, а кроме как через запятую, можно ли вывести это массивом, или объектами? Какие есть варианты кроме запятой?

Comment: Не возможно. В MySQL нет типа данных "массив". Обрабатывайте потом уже на php, explode делать не долго

Comment: Спасибо. Вы очень помогли. Можете написать кратко ответ, а я приму как решение. (для потомков)